# Could not load type Coypu.SessionConfiguration

Tags: coypu

I have created a Simple test with Coypu.

Below are the packages I have installed to use Coypu

```
<Package>
    <package id="Coypu" version="2.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Coypu.NUnit" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Selenium.Support" version="2.48.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="2.48.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Below is my code

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var sessionConfiguration = new SessionConfiguration
        {
            Browser = Browser.Firefox,
            AppHost = "example.com",
        };
    }
}
```

While running the test from Visual Studio Test Explorer, am getting the error message

```
System.LoadException : Could not load type 'Coypu.SessionConfiguration'from assembly Coypu, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken = null'
```

Am new to this Coypu and unable to proceed to implement this. kindly kelp to resolve this issue to proceed.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below example how to create browser session:

```
var sessionConfiguration = new SessionConfiguration
                                       {
                                           AppHost = "www.mypage.com",
                                           Port = 1111,
                                           SSL = false,
                                           Driver = typeof(SeleniumWebDriver),
                                           Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                           Browser = Browser.Firefox
                                       };
_browser = new BrowserSession(sessionConfiguration);
_browser.MaximiseWindow();
```